# Android - HttpsURLConnection not working

Tags: android, sockets, https, httpsurlconnection

I wrote this AsyncTask for sending small pieces of json through a HttpsURLConnection on an Android Phone. It's not throwing any exceptions in LogCat. But my Node.JS server(HTTPS!) does not receive any requests. What's wrong with this code? Thanks for your response!

```
    private class NetworkCommunication extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String paramUrl = params[0];
        String paramRequest = params[1];

        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };

        try {
            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslcontext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());
            Log.d("meet", "NetworkCommunication::setDefaultSSLSocketFactory()");

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    return true;
                }

            });
            Log.d("meet", "NetworkCommunication::setDefaultHostnameVerifier()");

            URL url = new URL(paramUrl);                
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d("meet", "NetworkCommunication::openConnection()");

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(paramRequest.getBytes().length));
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            Log.d("meet", "NetworkCommunication::set...()");

            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes(paramRequest);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            Log.d("meet", "NetworkCommunication::DataOutputStream");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("meet", "NetworkCommunication::Exception", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Log output:

```
    11-01 16:14:10.595: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 199K, 14% free 9660K/11143K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 39ms
11-01 16:14:10.595: D/dalvikvm(4265): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
11-01 16:14:10.715: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 277K, 14% free 9889K/11463K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 39ms
11-01 16:14:10.775: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 313K, 14% free 10121K/11719K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 27ms
11-01 16:14:10.775: D/dalvikvm(4265): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
11-01 16:14:10.780: D/dalvikvm(4265): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
11-01 16:14:10.790: D/AbsListView(4265): Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-01 16:14:10.835: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 251K, 13% free 10431K/11975K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 23ms
11-01 16:14:10.840: D/meet(4265): NetworkCommunication::setDefaultSSLSocketFactory()
11-01 16:14:10.840: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4265): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
11-01 16:14:10.845: D/meet(4265): NetworkCommunication::setDefaultHostnameVerifier()
11-01 16:14:10.845: D/meet(4265): NetworkCommunication::openConnection()
11-01 16:14:10.845: D/meet(4265): NetworkCommunication::set...()
11-01 16:14:10.890: D/libEGL(4265): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
11-01 16:14:10.890: D/libEGL(4265): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
11-01 16:14:10.895: D/libEGL(4265): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
11-01 16:14:10.895: D/(4265): Device driver API match
11-01 16:14:10.895: D/(4265): Device driver API version: 10
11-01 16:14:10.895: D/(4265): User space API version: 10 
11-01 16:14:10.895: D/(4265): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012 
11-01 16:14:10.915: D/OpenGLRenderer(4265): Enabling debug mode 0
11-01 16:14:10.980: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 245K, 15% free 10487K/12231K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
11-01 16:14:11.025: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 154K, 15% free 10486K/12231K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
11-01 16:14:11.045: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 15% free 10487K/12231K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
11-01 16:14:11.065: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 15% free 10486K/12231K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
11-01 16:14:11.100: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 178K, 15% free 10504K/12231K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
11-01 16:14:11.135: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 157K, 15% free 10514K/12231K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
11-01 16:14:11.160: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 169K, 15% free 10519K/12231K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
11-01 16:14:11.180: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 15% free 10519K/12231K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
11-01 16:14:11.285: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 15% free 10573K/12295K, paused 22ms+13ms, total 65ms
11-01 16:14:11.285: D/dalvikvm(4265): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 42ms
11-01 16:14:11.385: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 184K, 13% free 10902K/12423K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 54ms
11-01 16:14:11.445: D/meet(4265): NetworkCommunication::DataOutputStream
11-01 16:14:11.485: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 231K, 12% free 11228K/12743K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 32ms
11-01 16:14:11.485: D/dalvikvm(4265): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
11-01 16:14:11.485: D/dalvikvm(4265): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
11-01 16:14:11.490: D/dalvikvm(4265): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
11-01 16:14:11.490: D/dalvikvm(4265): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
11-01 16:14:11.555: D/dalvikvm(4265): GC_CONCURRENT freed 469K, 14% free 11399K/13191K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 28ms
```

Solution:
I must get the response, even if I don't want it. I added this code after "NetworkCommunication::DataOutputStream" and it worked!

```
InputStream istream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\n');
            }               
            Log.d("meet", "NetworkCommunication::response=" + response.toString());
```

Comment: any log at all ? how far have you gone, debugging-wise ?

Comment: Hello njzk2, thanks for your quick response. I don't know what you mean, but I attached the logfile under the code.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: I suggest you try to get the response from the request (after your "NetworkCommunication::DataOutputStream" flag), and see what it gets. It seems that your app is uploading data to somewhere, question is where?

Comment: It works. I must get the response(no matter if I need it or don't). Please post your comment so that I can accept it as answer and I will update my code in the question. Thank you!

Comment: @raptor: I did that and added another thought. Thank you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try to get the response from the request (after your "NetworkCommunication::DataOutputStream" flag), and see what it gets. It seems that your app is uploading data to somewhere, question is where?

Also, if you don't need the server response, you may try setting `connection.setDoInput(false)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing internet permission from manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: NO, the log cat would give the exception if the author did not set the required permission

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is more relied on the way you do `POST` json request.

You'll need to use `setEntity` method to set the HTTP request's header.

Here's a [example on Github](https://github.com/stefanklumpp/Simple-HTTP-Client/blob/master/src/com/devstream/http/HttpClient.java) about how to do `GET` and `POST`

For your convenient, I paste the relevant code here:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

                        StringEntity se;
                        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

                        // Set HTTP parameters
                        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
                        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // only set this parameter if you would like to use gzip compression

                        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
                        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");
```

Comment: Thanks! But this isn't working with HTTPS, isn't it?

Comment: setEntity is for HttpClient. The SO is using HttpURLConnection

Comment: @raptor sorry, I didn't check your question closely. My answer isn't correct for your question.